# Как вывести информацию о 4 рэндомных пользователях в столбец таблицы из MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно вывести изображение и 2 строки текста, а после еще и настроить отступы.  Как я только не пытался просто вывести, у меня ничего не получается.

php

```
$result88 = mysql_query("SELECT avatar,name,number FROM users ORDER BY RAND()",$db);
$myrow88 = mysql_fetch_array($result88)

print <<<HERE
<table>

<tr>

<td>
 </td>

<td>
//Вот сюда необходимо вывести
</td>
</tr>
</table>
HERE;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Писать код не буду, просто скажу, как можно вывести инфу о 4-ёх рандомных юзерах.

1. Надо вытащить все записи из таблицы БД, используя функцию **"mysql_fetch_array()"** Или ей подобные, например "mysql_fetch_assoc()".
2. Каждую полученную запись(строку) добавлять в ассоциативный массив. В итоге получится более сложная структура данных - двумерный массив, где первый индекс - номер строки, а второй - номер поля таблицы. Прямо, как таблица умножения =)
3. Затем просто четыре раза подбираете случайное число и ставите его в первый индекс сгенерированного массив, ну а потом просто выводите всю информацию в цикле, хранящуюся во втором индексе.

-

```
<?php
// подключаемся к базе данных
...
$struct = array();  // массив, где будем хранить строки из БД
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($select)) // $select - SQL-запрос
{
array_push($struct,$data) // вот она, двумерность!
}

for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) // 4 случайных юзера
{
$r = rand(1,count($struct));  // генерируем случайное число
for($j=0;$j<=count($data)-1;$j++) echo $struct[$r][$j]."<br>" //выводим
                                                               случайную строку
}    
?>
```

Comment: Ох как хотелось бы код увидеть)

Comment: Дополнил ответ)

Comment: Слуш не подскажешь как в столбец записать вот этот цикл и как потом настроить стили для каждого


   $result88 = mysql_query("SELECT login,avatar,name,number FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4",$db); //извлекаем логин и идентификатор пользователей 
            $myrow88 = mysql_fetch_array($result88);
      do {
   echo("<img src='$myrow88[avatar]'>");
             echo ($myrow88['login']);
     echo ($myrow88['name']);
      echo ($myrow88['number']);
 
} 
while ($myrow88 = mysql_fetch_array($result88));

Comment: стили в файле стилей настраиваются, назначаешь класс элементам и его уже "стилизируешь", напр. echo("<img class='ava' src='$myrow88[avatar]'>", ну а в столбец тут уже верстать лучше в полную меру, как вариант для теста просто <br/> поставить в конце выборки, непонятно что оно у вас там сейчас выводит чтобы точно ответить.

Comment: написал в конце "выборки" немного не правильно, в конце строки "вывода", так вернее.